# Linear transformation $R^{n\times n}$ to $R^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let B and C be given nxn matrices. Show that the following operation $L$ is a linear transformation from $R^{n\times n}$ to $R^{n\times n}: L(X) = BXC + C(X^t)B + BCX; X ∈ R^{n\times n}$, $t$ is the transpose.

I know how to work with linear transformations from $R^n$ to $R^m$, but how do I start solving this problem from $R^{n\times n}$ to $R^{n\times n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Show that for two matrices $X,Y$, we have

(1) $L(X+Y)=L(X)+L(Y)$ and for any scaler $\alpha$

(2) $L(\alpha X)=\alpha L(X)$.

Now

$L(X+Y)=B(X+Y)C+C(X+Y)^TB+BC(X+Y)=BXC+BYC+CX^TB+CY^TB+BCX++BCY$.

Find $L(X)+L(Y)$ and observe that the two expressions are equal, demonstrating (1).

Next Show (2).